# How do you code a continuous color palette that reflects color-blindness?

Tags: python, colors, color-palette

I suppose you could it for normal vision by "just" letting the RBG values in a tuple vary from 0 to 255, each, and recording them. But what about those that reflect color-blindness? Say I want to reproduce this palette:

[image]

How would I go about coding it?

I'm most familiar with Python but I'll learn another language if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "code a palette"? What exactly should be the input and the output of executing the code?

Comment: I don't know what the input would be, but the output should be a list of colors (in HEX, RGB etc.). I know ```sns.color_palette('rainbow', n)``` gives ```n``` values for the "usual" color palette. But palettes like that one above us can't be generated with this specific module. So how could I reproduce that palette (as a list of colors)?